# .gitignore does not ignore one folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got the following in my .gitignore:

```
#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
# files for the dex VM
*.dex
# Java class files
*.class
# generated files
bin/
gen/
# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db
# OSX files
.DS_Store
# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
# Android Studio
.idea
build/
cache.properties.lock
.idea/workspace.xml
*.iws
.gradle/
**/.gradle/
```

However, whenever I make changes to my app, git includes files like `.gradle/1.12/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock` to the commit.

What's wrong here? Why does it work with the folder `build/` but not with `.gradle/`?

Comment: It is most likely caused by some files in this folder already being tracked in git. Try running `git rm --cached .gradle` and commit the changes.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks, that worked! Seems like I thought .gitignore would do something it doesn't.

Comment: It does tell git to ignore new files when updating the index. If the index already tracks the file, it will be marked as modified anyway, as it is not new any longer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is possible that Git is already tracking these files. Running the following command in terminal worked for me for both `.gradle` and `.idea` files:

```
git rm --cached .gradle -r
```

Comment: thanks! this solved and removed these file, and what i exactly need

Answer (score 3):

This is common for dot(.) that are not included, add this to .gitignore

```
.*
!/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be because the git is already tracking those files. Stop tracking that file then do a commit and push.

In Source Tree:

- Right click the file and select stop tracking
- Commit the changes
- Push to origin

Comment: Please add: it is in Visual Studio Code, git tab.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, I hope this will help you:

- open your terminal and go to your root folder
- execute: `git rm -rf .gradle/`
- then execute this: `git rm --cached .gradle -r`
- commit your changes and sync again